# How to write my data saved in cookies in a site embedded in iframe & of other domain?

Tags: jquery, iframe, cookies

I have a site e.g. a.com in which I have data for say 5 input types. I saved the the data in cookies using click event.

Now I have embedded another site say b.com on the same page in an iframe. I want to fill the input types with respective data saved in cookies.

What I have tried? I have saved the data in cookies. Also trying to get the data from iframe using following jQuery

```
var $iframe = $('#iframe');
$iframe.ready(function() {
  var iBody = $iframe.contents().find("body");
  var myContent = iBody.find(".page-title");
  alert(myContent);
```

But could not fetch the data & fill the entries.

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to retrieve the cookies saved in domainA and send them through an iframe (hosted on domainA) to a site hosted on domainB - is that correct?

Comment: yes, absolutely! I know cookies can't be share. But what is the other mechanism?

Comment: No - this cannot work. You've gotten around the issue if cross-domain cookies by hosting the other domain in an iframe, but the issue still remains that you can access a cross-domain iframe in JS code for security reasons. What you are attempting to do is not possible.

Comment: what is the other mechanism?

Comment: There isn't one. You cannot access cross domain content, cookie, DOM or otherwise. The alternative is to send the data through GET/POST requests.